# why is my kernel/grub/fstab mounting my partition as EXT2 when its EXT4?

Tags: linux, mount, kernel, ext

so i am confused i recentl did full upgrade and since then i am unable to properly automatically mount my / partition yet /home partition mounts succsefully
here is some info before we start, this is the errror i am getting

```
[    4.225571] EXT2-fs (sdb2): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (2c0)
```

sooo what i did to work in this i did

```
 sudo mount -o remount,rw -t ext4 /dev/sdb2
```

which fixed my problem temporariy, but still after editing fstab to this the problem still remains

```
UUID=049f07ea-2dea-4234-b0e7-590a0e100091       /       ext4        remount,rw,noatime        0 1
#/dev/sdb2                             /               ext4            remount,rw         0 1
UUID=a3921c6f-b4e2-47fc-a5b6-2497636771e9       none        swap        sw      0 0
UUID=04748688-cc93-4212-aa18-89e16e68413a       /home       ext4        defaults    0 2
```

i even tried remvoing EXT2 support in my kernel with no luck

some info
i am using Getnoo with 4.20.3 kernelr verson 64bit, any ideas?

blkid output

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="564C75974C75729B" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="cce2a4b3-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="E6D656CCD6569C9D" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="cce2a4b3-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="linux" UUID="04748688-cc93-4212-aa18-89e16e68413a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cce2a4b3-03"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="B48658298657E9FE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b916b916-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="049f07ea-2dea-4234-b0e7-590a0e100091" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b916b916-02"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="8d263766-0e8b-4424-a889-e05a24a535cc" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="b916b916-03"
/dev/sdb4: UUID="82ea192f-cdc8-4e9e-b472-a7f10b20c302" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b916b916-04"
```

Comment: Looks like the `/dev/sdb2` line is commented out?

Comment: forgot to add blkid info, that thing above is sdb2, i tried it directly using /dev/sdb2 bvut same result so i just came back with UUID

Comment: Anything else in the syslog, when "couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features" appears in dmesg?

Comment: the only error in dmesg is the that i included